# Icons don't show for Google Chrome Extensions

Tags: html, json, google-chrome

I'm trying to code a simple Google Chrome Extension. Everything is alright apart from my icons.

Below is my json file:

```json
{
    "name": "Wikipedia Quick Search",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Easily access Wikipedia from your page",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "icons": {
        "16": "search16.png",
        "32": "search32.png",
        "48": "search48.png",
        "128": "search128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "search16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Quick Search"
    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

The icon names are all correct and scaled accordingly to the size requirements, but in chrome://extensions, the icons don't show up.

Comment: You should format your json-code as code block, use three back ticks.

Comment: Even after formatting the icons don't show

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/icons/

This is the website I used to get the specifications for the icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.

My computer was not able to properly convert my original images from JPG to PNG.
Used an online JPG to PNG converter and it worked wonders.